# how can remove chunks in vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I cant remove chunks in project with vite in vue3

vite.config.js

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {},
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [discussion on Github](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2756#issuecomment-951370238), you can use

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: () => 'everything.js',
      },
    },
  },
});
```